# Adding together two column sums in SQL Server2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, view, sum

Ive come across a problem when trying to add together two column sums. 
Ive created a view with all the correct data in but when i try to execute a query like:

```
    Select ID, Sum(ColumnA),
    Sum(ColumnB)
    Sum(ColumnA) + Sum(ColumnB) AS ColumnC
    From View1
   Group by ID
```

The ColumnC figure is only correct when there is data in both columns, if there is only data in ColumnB then it displays that but if there is only data in ColumnA then it doesnt.

Sometime when there isnt any data in ColumnA or B it will be NULL, so maybe this is the problem. 
Hope there is a way around this.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But thanks for the answers they were great and all worked, i chose to opt for the IS NULL clause in the ended. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to substitute zeros for NULLs:

```
Select ID, Sum(ColumnA),
Sum(ColumnB)
ISNULL(Sum(ColumnA),0) + ISNULL(Sum(ColumnB),0) AS ColumnC
From View1
Group by ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding something to a null value gives a null result, the null is not converted to zero. You have to do that conversion explicitly:

```
Select ID, Sum(ColumnA),
Sum(ColumnB)
isnull(Sum(ColumnA), 0) + isnull(Sum(ColumnB), 0) AS ColumnC
From View1
Group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace `NULL` inputs to the calculation with zero as below.

```
COALESCE(Sum(ColumnA),0) + COALESCE(Sum(ColumnB),0) +  AS ColumnC
```

Or `ISNULL` as in the other 2 answers. [Doesn't matter which](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx) if portability is not a concern.